# Load COPY (Cobol) file in Talend tool

Tags: talend, cobol

I would like to load a file in Talend which is supposed to have compress data inside. I don't know how to do that, I mean I don't know neither load a COPY file nor a COPY file with compress data. May someone help me please?

These are sample files (one of them is the schema): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bqvcw0dk56hqhh2/AABbs1GRKjo7rycQrcUM_dgta?dl=0

P.S.: I know how to load csv, Excel, data from SQL databases, among others. However, I don't know how to handle this kind of files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more specific details

Comment: These are sample files (one of them is the schema): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bqvcw0dk56hqhh2/AABbs1GRKjo7rycQrcUM_dgta?dl=0

Comment: What you are facing is not compress data but variable-length records.

The COPY file contains descriptions of the different possible data segments.

Comment: Depending of the first 4 characters of each line, you must apply one of each structures (RFVMSCG, RGFVMSCG or RHFVMSCG).